# CUDA filtering a queue

Tags: filter, cuda, queue, gpu, gpgpu

**Short version**: how do I implement an efficient filter operation in CUDA?

**Long version**:
I have a CUDA code that follows a queue filtering semantic.
I have ~5 million initial elements in the queue and the code filters them using an "expensive" stage-wise computation. 
The end result is expected to retain ~1000 elements, and a each stage the number of removed elements follows an exponential decay curve (i.e. the first stages remove a lot, the last stages remove little).

Since in the GPU each element is processed in parallel (by blocks of threads), simply running "all stages over all elements" is quite waste-full. At a given stage, one element may be retained, all others may be already removed, but computation continues over all remaining stages even for elements already "ready to be removed".

A more efficient approach would be to run each stage separately, reading an input list and storing results an intermediary output list; and then keep things running in a ping-pong schema.
Doing this however generates significant global memory read-writes, and more importantly puts pressure on an atomicInc that synchronizes the concurrent write on the output list.

> How would you suggest to do such stage-wise filtering ?

Thanks for your answers and suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use `compact` or `remove_if`. You can use `CUDPP` library or `thrust`. You cannot avoid writing to global memory after each stage unless you will compute all stages over all elements.

This is simple pseudocode:

1. Init memory etc.
2. foreach stage do
3. Run filtering for all elements
4. Use compact/remove_if for all elements
5. Rewrite elements or do something else (depends on used library)
6. If last stage break else goto 4

Comment: Also look into `thrust::copy_if`. I think `remove_if` is a sort, which may be more expensive in your case. Also look into the ArrayFire library, which is free for a single GPU. If you want to implement your own algorithm, read [Optimizing Parallel Reduction in CUDA](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf).